# How to do subplot for each month?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have grouped the dataset by month and date and I have added third column for count the data in each day.

**Dataframe before**

```
    month   day  
0    1      1   
1    1      1    
2    1      1      
..
3000 12      31   
3001 12      31   
3002 12      31
```

**Dataframe now:**

```
   month   day  count
0    1      1    300
1    1      2    500
2    1      3    350  
..
363  12      28   700
364  12      29   1300
365  12      30   1000
```

How to do subplot for each month , x will be the days and y will be the count

```
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    %matplotlib inline
    df= pd.read_csv('/home/rand/Downloads/Flights.csv')
    by_month= df.groupby(['month','day']).day.agg('count').to_frame('count').reset_index()
```

I'm beginner in data science field

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please always provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People won't be able to help if they do not know how your dataframe is looking, for example.

Comment: @Rawan2018 it is difficult to 'Verify' from the Dataframe you included. To correctly answer your question we would have to test our code on the dataframe you provided us. We cannot do this if you include dataframe in the manner you have provided. Give us a dataframe we can test our code on.

Comment: @SaketKumarSingh ok but the size of the csv file is big

Comment: @Rawan2018 in that case give a representative sample of the dataset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xticks(df['day'].unique())
df.groupby(["day", "month"]).mean()['count'].unstack().plot(ax=ax)
```

Above code will give you 12 lines representing each month in one plot. If you want to have 12 individual subplots for those months, try this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
for i in range(1,13):
    df_monthly = df[df['month'] == i] # select dataframe with month = i
    ax = fig.add_subplot(12,1,i) # add subplot in the i-th position on a grid 12x1   
    ax.plot(df_monthly['day'], df_monthly['count'])
    ax.set_xticks(df_monthly['day'].unique()) # set x axis
```

Comment: It produce (keyError: 'count')

Comment: do you have column 'count'?

Comment: yes, I have added it after grouping the dataframe by_month= 
   df.groupby(['month','day']).day.agg('count').to_frame('count').reset_index()

Comment: now It runs but in one plot I want 12 plots , the error because the count column in by_month not df

Comment: I assumed you have dataframe df that had already had those 3 columns. Do you want 12 lines in one plot or 12 subplots?

Comment: I want 12 subplot for each month that contains one line witch represent count column

Comment: The idea is creating subplots by loop. I will edit the anawer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use `pandas.DataFrame.pivot` to change the shape of your table to make it more convenient for the plot. So in your code you could do something like this:

```
 plot_data= df.pivot(index='day', columns='month', values='count')
 plot_data.plot()
 plt.show()
```

This is assuming you have equal number of days in every month since in the sample you included, month 12 only has 30 days. More on [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html).

Comment: oh sorry that's my mistake , month 12 has 31 day, I edited my question

Comment: @Rawan2018 it will work regardless, except would give you NA values for places that are not in your dataset

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'month': list(range(1, 13))*3, 
    'days': np.random.randint(1,11, 12*3), 
    'count': np.random.randint(10,20, 12*3)})

df.set_index(['month', 'days'], inplace=True)
df.sort_index()

df = df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).sum()
```

[image]

Code to plot it:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.pivot(index='days', columns='month', values='count').fillna(0).plot()
```

Comment: I have grouped it but I don't know how to plot them